# How to dequeue styles coming from plugins?

Tags: css

I'm trying to reduce the overloading by not to load all style sheets on my website's homepage. 
Some of those sheets is coming and loading from external plugins like woo-commerce, 
I have tried to do that using `wp_dequeue_style` function, but it haven't worked, those style sheets still being loaded! 
For example, the first one is 100% not used:

[image: This style sheet coming from woo-commerce]

When I use the code below:

```
function disable_plugins_style()
{
    global $wp_styles;
    wp_dequeue_style('style-rtl');
    wp_deregister_style('style-rtl');
    unset($wp_styles->registered['style-rtl']);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_plugins_style', 9999);
add_action('wp_head', 'disable_plugins_style', 9999);
```

It didn't cause any affect, could I find someone can help me please.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track, but you need to know the stylesheet's ID. It's not necessarily the same as the stylesheet's filename.

Check the generated source of your page (ie, load the page up in a browser and View Source). Find the `<link>` tag that's loading the stylesheet. If it's been properly enqueued for WordPress, it should look something like:

```
<link
 rel="stylesheet"
 id="your-stylesheet-id-css"
 href="https://example.com/path/to/your-stylesheet.css"
/>
```

You need to take the value in the `id` attribute and trim the `-css` from the end.

So, in my example, you'd need:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_382138_unload_css', 9999 );
function wpse_382138_unload_css() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'your-stylesheet-id' );
}
```

...changing `your-stylesheet-id` to the value you find in your page's generated source code.

### References

- [`wp_dequeue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/)

Answer (score 2):

Your basic strategy is correct. The problem is that, although there are some best practices, you can't never know for sure in a easy way, 100% of time:

1. when a plugin or theme will enqueue scripts and styles;
2. what priority is used to enqueue
3. if a plugin or theme really used enqueue/register hooks or hard-coded.

That said, you might want to a) **hook your code to different actions when the scripts and styles are printed** (*and not enqueued*) and test different priorities. Or b) you could check each plugin and theme code and see what hook and priority are used to each `wp_enqueue_script` or `wp_enqueue_style` call.

I would suggest going with option a, something like this:

```
    function wpse_382138_disable_plugins_style()
    {
        //these should use the same priority of later than the priority used by the plugin or theme when hooked
        wp_dequeue_style('stylesheet-handler-with-default-priority');
        wp_dequeue_style('stylesheet-handler-with-explicit-default-priorit', 10);
        wp_dequeue_style('stylesheet-handler-with-later-priority', 20);
    }
    function wpse_382138_disable_plugins_scripts()
    {
        // these should use the same priority of later than the priority used by the plugin or theme when hooked
        wp_dequeue_script('script-handler-with-default-priority');
        wp_dequeue_script('script-handler-with-explicit-default-priority', 10);
        wp_dequeue_script('script-handler-with-later-priority', 20);
    }

    // option A: hook your unhooking functions either to hooks later than wp_enqueue_scripts or wp_enqueue_style as wp_head or wp_footer.
    add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_382138_disable_plugins_style', 10);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wpse_382138_disable_plugins_style', 10);
    add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_382138_disable_plugins_scripts', 10);
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wpse_382138_disable_plugins_scripts', 10);

    // option b: hook your unhooking functions to the printing actions with a priority lower than the before first scripts or styles are usuarlly written, so they will execute the dequeue before scripts and styles are printed.
    add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'wpse_382138_disable_plugins_style', 5);
    add_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', 'wpse_382138_disable_plugins_style', 5);
    add_action('wp_print_styles', 'wpse_382138_isable_plugins_scrips', 5);
```

[This Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request) has a list of almost all hooks triggered in a typical WordPress Request.

Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: According to the User Notes on [the `wp_dequeue_style()` docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/), you need to hook at a *higher* priority than the initial `wp_enqueue_style()` call, to make sure the stylesheet's already been enqueued. So `5` is probably too early, since the default priority is `10`.

Comment: What I wanted to convey is that he hooks his "unhooking function" before the printing. And this unhooking function would then unhook each individual handler, and here, it should use 10 or later. But my answer were not properly showing this and there were some mistakes. I edited and improved it to clarity. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Adding wp_deregister_style to the function may also help: ([Tweak to Pat J's code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/382138/how-to-dequeue-styles-coming-from-plugins#answer-382158))

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_382138_unload_css', 9999 );
function wpse_382138_unload_css() {
  wp_dequeue_style( 'your-stylesheet-id' );
  wp_deregister_style( 'your-stylesheet-id' );
}
```